# How can I stop bots from a url from being able to access my site? (Using Nginx)

Tags: nginx

I'm getting visits from a bot at something like `crawl.unwanted.com` and would like to stop all traffic to my nginx site from 'unwanted.com`.

Is there a way in nginx to block access by url or only by IP? (I don't know their IP(s)).

Is there another better way to stop this website specifically from accessing my site?  Thank you

Expected results: This malicious bot should no longer be able to visit my site.

Comment: If you are able to figure out the source address of the site then you can write code to return the bad request response .

Comment: Nothing can be done with the URL?

Comment: You can do with the URL too... all you need to do is figure out the URL and return the response before it hits to the application code...